# Fast syncing showing endless importing new state entries Geth 1.7.3

Tags: go-ethereum, myetherwallet, geth-debugging

I used this command to sync to the chain

```
geth --fast --cache=1024 --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" upgradedb
```

And then when I was nearing the latest block it showed me the log below

```
INFO [01-25|09:04:47] Imported new state entries               count=1111 elapsed=5.767ms   processed=578324 pending=7057  retry=247 duplicate=0 unexpected=589
INFO [01-25|09:04:47] Imported new state entries               count=1230 elapsed=7.861ms   processed=579554 pending=6333  retry=3   duplicate=0 unexpected=589
INFO [01-25|09:04:47] Imported new state entries               count=692  elapsed=5.302ms   processed=580246 pending=8732  retry=59  duplicate=0 unexpected=589
INFO [01-25|09:04:48] Imported new state entries               count=380  elapsed=1.089ms   processed=580626 pending=11689 retry=6   duplicate=0 unexpected=589
INFO [01-25|09:04:48] Imported new state entries               count=606  elapsed=2.862ms   processed=581232 pending=13363 retry=147 duplicate=0 unexpected=589
INFO [01-25|09:04:48] Imported new state entries               count=1094 elapsed=14.179ms  processed=582326 pending=13632 retry=57  duplicate=0 unexpected=589
INFO [01-25|09:04:49] Imported new state entries               count=1088 elapsed=7.410ms   processed=583414 pending=13311 retry=4   duplicate=0 unexpected=589
INFO [01-25|09:04:49] Imported new state entries               count=1341 elapsed=17.202ms  processed=584755 pending=12515 retry=6   duplicate=0 unexpected=589
INFO [01-25|09:04:49] Imported new state entries               count=1070 elapsed=9.520ms   processed=585825 pending=12432 retry=6   duplicate=0 unexpected=589
INFO [01-25|09:04:50] Imported new state entries               count=1378 elapsed=8.078ms   processed=587203 pending=11904 retry=4   duplicate=0 unexpected=589
INFO [01-25|09:04:50] Imported new state entries               count=1131 elapsed=10.760ms  processed=588334 pending=11949 retry=4   duplicate=0 unexpected=589
```

Based from the `duplicate` and `unexpected` values, it's basically the same thing. Does this mean that I haven't still synced in the Main Network? It's becoming endless unlike the one in the Test Network. My wallet balance isn't updating because of this and I think it's due to `--fast` needing to have a completely synced chain before updating the balances. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 7):

If you see that, you aren't yet synchronized, not even close. You are just done with the block download phase and still running the state downloads. You can see this yourself via the seemingly endless `Imported state entries [...]` stream of logs. You'll need to wait that out too before your node comes truly online.

More informations here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16251

But I don't know how long this will take. I'm at `processed=78300000` and it's still running.

Answer (score 1):

1. use parity
2. make sure your harddisk is SSD.
3. Memory > 4GB at least.
4. multiple core CPU